# Ionic 4 SCSS In Page Is Being Ignored

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I'm having a nightmare trying to get SCSS to work in a page in ionic 4. I'm using the scss file that is generated when you create a page with: ionic generate page

So the component is importing the file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-singleform',
  templateUrl: './singleform.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./singleform.page.scss'],
})
```

In the single form.page.scss file all i am trying to do is change .input-wrapper from display:flex to display:block and nothing happens:

```
.input-wrapper {
  display: block !important;
}
```

I can actually see the code is loaded in via the dom inspector, it's just not applied to the input-wrapper around the label and input field; it's still showing display: flex

I've had these issues constantly, none of the scss ever seems to do anything!

Comment: add your CSS in global.css,
//page selector
app-register {
    .input-wrapper {
        display: block !important;
      }
}

Comment: @user9088454 thanks for the answer, however that also doesn't work! Inspecting in chrome it still says flex

Comment: what kind of view you want?

Comment: Basically, i just want the form label to be above the field, not next to it, changing the wrapper to display block would solve it but it just won't change no matter where i put the css.

Comment: @GlenElkins You can take that format of input with this. <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="stacked">Stacked Label</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

Comment: it is complicated with Ionic 4 as not everything is available due to the magic of web components and shadow dom. I've been limping along as well trying to understand this, but I guess it's time to research it in more detail as its not going away.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<!-- Inputs with Floating labels -->
<ion-item>
<ion-label position="floating">Floating Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<!-- Inputs with Stacked labels -->
<ion-item>
<ion-label position="stacked">Stacked Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

For more details check it out: [ion-input](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input)